# How do I fix : 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, object, int, iterable

I'm trying to run this piece of code and I am receiving an error message `'int' object is not iterable for line 10`. Not sure where I've gone wrong.

```
def inputVal(prompt,lower,upper):
    print(prompt)
    retVal = int(input())
    while retVal<lower or retVal>upper:
        print('Incorrect Value')
        retVal = int(input())
    return retVal

numComp = inputVal("Please enter number of competitors", 5, 20)

for comp in numComp:
    total=0
    for i in range(5):
        judgescore = inputVal('Please input judges score', 0, 10)
        total = total + judgescore
    print("Total judge score for competitor ", comp+1, "is: ", total)
    print("Average judge score for competitor ", comp+1, "is: ", total/5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's coming from this line:

```
for comp in numComp:
```

Because `numComp` is an `int` that comes from the user. And `int`s can't be iterated over (doesn't make any sense to iterate over a number)

Perhaps you meant:

```
for comp in range(numComp):
```